# Is it possible to import a music or sound file into flutter Assets

Tags: android, flutter, developer-tools

Please , I have two questions to ask
Is it possible to import a music  or sound file into flutter assets, if not, what's the best way to import a music files into flutter.
my second question is,
In a Food ordering app, how can I send a message to the user's number about a summary/review of what he/she order.
Also how can I receive a message of what the user have order, in other words, how can I know what a user have ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flutter documentation on how to read and write files to device https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/

As your other questions (they really should be a separate post from your first question) you could try Firebase 
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ 
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: Avoid links in general are they won't necesseraly live forever. Consider quoting the important content

Comment: Thanks Rémi will do in future